# In bash, storing "permission denied" when trying to delete files

Tags: bash

I'm trying to delete dynamically created files (Xcode derived data). But, periodically some of the deletions fail because of permission denied. If the deletes were successful, I'd like to continue. Otherwise, stop.

Checking for the status using $? always yields 0 because `$ rm -fRv` was executed successfully, but that's not too useful. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
# Delete derived data
function ddd () {
    echo "Deleting derived data."
    
    # something like this for determining if the deletes were successful
    local success
    success=$(rm -fRv "${HOME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData")

    if [ ! "${success}" ]; then
        echo "Derived data could not be deleted"
        return 1
    fi

    echo "Successfully deleted derived data"
}
```

Comment: Don't use `-f`? `errors=$( ( chmod -R +w "$dir" && rm -r "$dir" ) <&- 2>&1 ); if [ $? != 0 ]; then printf 'Errors:\n%s' "$errors"; ...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'force' flag has the side effect of ignoring errors (including non-existing flag). Consider instead using

```
if ! rm -R "${HOME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" ; then
    echo "Derived data could not be deleted"
    return 1
fi
```

From 'rm' man:

```
-f, --force
ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
```

The down side is that the 'rm -R' will stop at the first error. As an alternative, which will try to remove as much as possible

```
# Delete as much as possible
rm -rvf "${HOME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"

# Check if folder was actually removed
if ! -e "${HOME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" ; then
    echo "Derived data could not be deleted"
    return 1
fi
```